# Glances' sensors plug-in: "No such file or directory: '/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/name'"

Tags: monitoring

I use [Glances](https://nicolargo.github.io/glances/)  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170315035752/https://nicolargo.github.io/glances/)) to monitor on my computer (Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS x64 + `Glances==2.8.5`. Upgrading to the latest version `Glances==2.8.8` did not help).

After installing the  [sensors](http://glances.readthedocs.io/en/stable/aoa/sensors.html)  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170315035306/http://glances.readthedocs.io/en/stable/aoa/sensors.html)) plug-in, I get this error message whenever I tried to run `sudo glances`:

```
mlee@server:~$ sudo glances
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/glances", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Glances==2.8.5', 'console_scripts', 'glances')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glances/__init__.py", line 225, in main
    start_standalone(config=config, args=args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glances/__init__.py", line 105, in start_standalone
    standalone = GlancesStandalone(config=config, args=args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glances/standalone.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.stats = GlancesStats(config=config, args=args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glances/stats.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.load_modules(self.args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glances/stats.py", line 77, in load_modules
    self.load_plugins(args=args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glances/stats.py", line 105, in load_plugins
    self._plugins[plugin_name] = plugin.Plugin(args=args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glances/plugins/glances_sensors.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.glancesgrabsensors = GlancesGrabSensors()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glances/plugins/glances_sensors.py", line 229, in __init__
    self.stemps = psutil.sensors_temperatures()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 2212, in sensors_temperatures
    rawdict = _psplatform.sensors_temperatures()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psutil/_pslinux.py", line 1108, in sensors_temperatures
    binary=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psutil/_pslinux.py", line 298, in cat
    with open_binary(fname) if binary else open_text(fname) as f:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psutil/_pslinux.py", line 204, in open_text
    return open(fname, "rt", **kwargs)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/name'
```

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install -y lm-sensors
sudo apt-get install -y hddtemp
sudo pip install PsUtil
```

It didn't help. What do I need to do so that `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/name` contains something that satisfies `glances`?

---

Output of `sensor`:

```
mlee@server:~$ sensors
power_meter-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
power1:      290.00 W  (interval =   1.00 s)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +35.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 0:         +26.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 2:         +30.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 3:         +35.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 4:         +28.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 8:         +25.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 10:        +26.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 11:        +32.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 12:        +28.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0001
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 1:  +34.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 0:         +31.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 2:         +27.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 3:         +26.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 4:         +26.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 8:         +26.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 10:        +33.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 11:        +29.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 12:        +26.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
```

Output of `ls /sys/bus/platform/devices/`:

```
mlee@server:~$ ls /sys/bus/platform/devices/
alarmtimer        GHES.1            iTCO_wdt                reg-dummy
coretemp.0        GHES.2            microcode               serial8250
coretemp.1        gpio_ich          pcspkr
Fixed MDIO bus.0  ipmi_bmc.0852.32  platform-framebuffer.0
```

Output of `grep HWMON /boot/config-3.13.0-100-generic`:

```
mlee@server:/scratch$ grep HWMON /boot/config-3.13.0-100-generic
CONFIG_IGB_HWMON=y
CONFIG_IXGBE_HWMON=y
CONFIG_HWMON=y
CONFIG_HWMON_VID=m
# CONFIG_HWMON_DEBUG_CHIP is not set
CONFIG_SENSORS_IIO_HWMON=m
CONFIG_THERMAL_HWMON=y
```

Output of `uname -r`:

```
mlee@server:/scratch$ uname -r
3.13.0-100-generic
```

Comment: Kernel driver for some hardware monitoring ("hwmon") device(s) show up in this directory. Though I'd say it's a bug that the plugin just fails if none of those is present, and you should make a bug report. What's the output of `sensors`?

Comment: @dirkt  Thank you, I have added the  output of `sensor`  in the answer.

Comment: @dirkt I have posted the same question on Glances forum (to check before making a bug report): https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/glances-users/78kZlU2egzo (I cannot archive the page due to `robots.txt`, why do some people still use Google groups…)

Comment: Hm. I also have a `coretemp-isa-0000` output, which *does* show up in `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0`. So it might be reasonable assumption to expect this sysentry. Do you have `coretemp*` entries in `/sys/bus/platform/devices/`?

Comment: @dirkt I have added the output of `ls /sys/bus/platform/devices/` in the answer. I do have `coretemp*` entries.

Comment: Ok, so the drivers are properly loaded. What does `grep HWMON your-kernel-config` say for your kernel? In Debian, kernel configs are in `/boot/`, so I assume they should be for Ubuntu, too.

Comment: @dirkt hmm when I tried to run `hwmon` I obtain `-bash: hwmon: command not found`. Is that expected? Same with `HWMON`.

Comment: "Hwmon" is not a program, so you can't run it. So yes, that's expected. As I said, the next step is to check if your kernel is configured for hardware monitoring, so that it populates `/sys/class/hwmon`. All "files" inside `/sys` are really interfaces to the kernel.

Comment: @dirkt Thanks for the explanation, I have added the output of `grep HWMON /boot/config-3.13.0-100-generic` to the answer.

Comment: Ok, HWMON is enabled, but it doesn't show up. That's difficult to debug remotely. Look through the output of `dmesg` right after you boot, and see if you find any error message. I looked through mine right now, and apparently the involved modules don't leave messages if they start up properly, so it might be they don't leave messages by default. What I'd do next would be to see if you can enable debugging messages for those modules, recompile the kernel and look for the problem. But without debugging experience that's hard to do for you.